# Importing an .fbx file and exporting as .stl results in a blocky model (3d printing)

Tags: 3d-printing, .fbx, stl

Trying to make some models into .stl so that I can 3d print, but when I export my .fbx as an .stl, the model ends up looking blocky in a way.

Assuming anyone understands what I mean by blocky, what can I do unless this doesn't matter with 3d printing?

[image]

Comment: you have 702 overlapping duplicate vertices for your body mesh and 300 overlapping duplicate vertices for the head mesh. select them all and press `m` > *By Distance*. Then the "blockiness" is not a problem. It's just that you did not apply shade smooth after importing. The mesh is also not nice for 3D printing as it is low resolution triangles. You could try increase it with high level Subdivision Modifier.

Comment: But I would recommend remeshing it as quads as the topology is very poor.

Comment: What's the worst that can happen with low resolution triangles? Is it definitively not going to work? As much as I've used Blender I'm still not great at this stuff so any help would be great with your suggestions

Comment: it will work as long as it is manifold. but it will look blocky like when it's flat shaded. but you can add more subdivisions using subdivision modifier and apply it. to reduce the blockiness

Comment: What do you mean by manifold?

Comment: I checked again but unfortunately your mesh is not manifold so the 3d print will fail. read more about it here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry

Comment: I'm working on fixing the manifold stuff now, but how do I make it smooth so it isn't blocky? I can't shade smooth because on export it'll just become blocky again

Comment: just add subdivision modifier so it adds more geometry. the higher the level the more subdivisions. did you manage to resolve the manifoldness? :D